# is it possible to output muliple lines in console.log in one border?

Tags: javascript, css, console.log

I'm trying to get a console.log with styling like this:

```
    let style='border: 3px solid red; display:inline-block; padding:10px; white-space:pre;';
console.log(
    `%cLine1\nLine2`,
    style
);
```

I would like to keep both lines in 1 border, but the \n makes two borders:

[image: this is not the desired output]

Comment: what do you mean with borders, u mean its bold  in the middle?

Comment: no.. i mean.. now line 1 and line 2 both have their own red border. I would like to have both in one red border.

Answer (score 1):

This may be help you I will update code if there is any another method

```
open browser console to preview code
```

```js
let css1 = 'border: 3px solid red; display:inline-block; padding:10px; white-space:pre;border-bottom:none';

let css2 = 'border: 3px solid red; display:inline-block; padding:10px; white-space:pre;border-top:none;margin-top:-8px';

console.log(`%cLine1`, css1);
console.log(`%cLine2`, css2);
```

Answer (score -1):

I came up with this solution. It is in part inspired by @dev.skas's answer.
See the browser console to see the output.

```js
const styling = (marginTop) => {
return `border: 3px solid red; display:inline-block; padding:10px; white-space:pre;margin-top:-${marginTop}px`
}

console.log(`%cLine1`, styling(0));
console.log(`%cLine2`, styling(8));
```